# Join tables to retrieve data in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

These are my table details:

Table1

```
id       name
----------------
101      syed
102      shaik
```

Table2

```
l_id     sup_id
-----------------
101     102


id  name    sup_id  sup_name
------------------------------
101 syed    102     shaik
```

In table-1 I have two rows, 101 and 102 which is a master table. Table 2 consists of supervisor login ids with their subordinate ids. The common column between table1 and table2 is id & l_id. So, I'm trying to pull the data as follows to get the details.

My query is as follows

```
SELECT 
    r.id, 
    trim(r.name) as name, trim(a.sup_id) as sup_id,
    trim(select name from schema.table1 
         where id in (a.sup_id)) as sup_name 
FROM 
    schema.table1 r
JOIN
    schema.table2 a ON a.l_id = r.id 
WHERE 
    r.id IN (101)
```

I'm able to get till supervisor id, but not supervisor name.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

```
person id - person name - supervisor id - supervisor name
```

Comment: Please, show your current script and explain, why you cannot join `table1` and `table2` 2 times by different `id` from `table2`?

Comment: @astentx, updated with script

Comment: You can join any (of course, it is limited, but you hardly can hit that number) number of tables and use a single table any number of times in `join`, but should use alias for each occurrence (`JOIN tabname as tabalias`). No need to do subquery in select, it often performs bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select t1.id,t1.name, sup_id,t2.name as sup_name
from table2 t 
     join table1 t1 on t1.id=t.l_id
     join table1 t2 on t2.id=t.sup_id
```

Comment: What is the alias you have to connect to sup_id?

Comment: it's the t2.id which is a reference of table1 @Syed - you need to join your table2 with the multiple instances of table1

Comment: join table1 t2 on t2.id=t.sup_id --> In this statement, there is no id column in t2 table. There is only l_id and sup_id columns

Comment: @Syed, t2 is an alias of table1 and table1 has an id column which is used for joining with sup_id